# Logistic regression power analysis with moderation between categorical and continuous variable

Tags: r, logistic, interaction, sample-size, statistical-power

I've been reading [Simulation of logistic regression power analysis - designed experiments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments/35994#35994?newreg=4676cdfba08b48449c8c06ba4bdcb71a), http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2009/06/example-72-simulate-data-from-logistic.html, and [Power analysis for ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/power-analysis-for-ordinal-logistic-regression?lq=1) and I'm still a little lost on how to do a power analysis for my data. I want to be able to determine what N I should have if I have an interaction between a categorical variable (with 3 levels) and a continuous variable.

[Simulation of logistic regression power analysis - designed experiments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35940/simulation-of-logistic-regression-power-analysis-designed-experiments/35994#35994?newreg=4676cdfba08b48449c8c06ba4bdcb71a) provides some information, but I can't figure out how to simulate the relationship between the categorical and continuous variables and outcome.

> set.seed(1)
>
> repetitions = 1000
>   N = 10000
>   n = N/8
>   var1  = c(   .03,    .03,    .03,    .03,    .06,    .06,    .09,   .09)
>   var2  = c(     0,      0,      0,      1,      0,      1,      0,     1)
>   rates = c(0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.00395, 0.003, 0.0042, 0.0035, 0.002)
>
> var1    = rep(var1, times=n)
>   var2    = rep(var2, times=n)
>   var12   = var1**2
>   var1x2  = var1 *var2
>   var12x2 = var12*var2
>
> significant = matrix(nrow=repetitions, ncol=7)
>
> startT = proc.time()[3]
>   for(i in 1:repetitions){
>    responses          = rbinom(n=N, size=1, prob=rates)
>    model              = glm(responses~var1+var2+var12+var1x2+var12x2, 
>                             family=binomial(link="logit"))
>    significant[i,1:5] = (summary(model)$coefficients[2:6,4]<.05)<br>
> >      significant[i,6]   = sum(significant[i,1:5])<br>
> >      modelDev           = model$null.deviance-model$deviance
>    significant[i,7]   = (1-pchisq(modelDev, 5))<.05
>   }
>   endT = proc.time()[3]
>   endT-startT
>
> sum(significant[,1])/repetitions      # pre-specified effect power for var1
>   [1] 0.042
>   sum(significant[,2])/repetitions      # pre-specified effect power for var2
>   [1] 0.017
>   sum(significant[,3])/repetitions      # pre-specified effect power for var12
>   [1] 0.035
>   sum(significant[,4])/repetitions      # pre-specified effect power for var1X2
>   [1] 0.019
>   sum(significant[,5])/repetitions      # pre-specified effect power for var12X2
>   [1] 0.022
>   sum(significant[,7])/repetitions      # power for likelihood ratio test of model
>   [1] 0.168
>   sum(significant[,6]==5)/repetitions   # all effects power
>   [1] 0.001
>   sum(significant[,6]>0)/repetitions    # any effect power
>   [1] 0.065
>   sum(significant[,4]&significant[,5])/repetitions   # power for interaction terms
>   [1] 0.017

I feel like I should be able to adapt the code from [Power analysis for ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22406/power-analysis-for-ordinal-logistic-regression?lq=1) and that this would be a better, more succinct option

> library(rms)
>
> tmpfun <- function(n, beta0, beta1, beta2) { 
>      x <- runif(n, 0, 10) 
>      eta1 <- beta0 + beta1*x 
>      eta2 <- eta1 + beta2 
>      p1 <- exp(eta1)/(1+exp(eta1)) 
>      p2 <- exp(eta2)/(1+exp(eta2)) 
>      tmp <- runif(n) 
>      y <- (tmp < p1) + (tmp < p2) 
>      fit <- lrm(y~x) 
>      fit$stats[5] 
>   }
>
> out <- replicate(1000, tmpfun(100, -1/2, 1/4, 1/4)) 
>   mean( out < 0.05 )

but I'm not completely sure how to do so. I'm assuming tmpfun(100,-1/2, 1/4,1/4) is specifying the N and betas that you want, but how do I adjust tmpfun to another (categorical) variable and include an interaction term? Ultimately the equation should include 6 betas: the intercept, the beta for x, the beta for z1, the beta for z2, the interaction term between x and z1, and the interaction term between x and z2.

Finally, I can't find any reliable sources on what sorts of "effect sizes" I should be using as small or medium.

Let me know if I can provide more information!