# Power analysis for Ordinal Regression

Tags: references, statistical-power, ordered-logit

I am looking for a resource to conduct power analysis for an ordinal regression that includes several predictors (there is no "treatment group"). I found a great simulation method first suggested by Snow here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22410/231675). But I am not sure how to modify this to include more independent variables (in my case, 6). Another person had a similar question, and I was hoping that by posting it as it's own question I might get an answer. I understand that I should 'include them all in the eta1 piece, e.g. eta1 <- beta0 + beta1*x1 + beta2*x2 + beta3*x3'' (as mentioned in another comment on the page). But I do not know how to adjust the rest of the parameters in the function. Could someone help me out with this?