# Power simulation for Difference-in-Difference

Tags: r, statistical-power, difference-in-difference

Referring to the simulation approach suggested by Snow for ordinal logistic regression: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22410/231675

> Here is a simple example with ordinal regression:
>
> ```
> library(rms)
>
> tmpfun <- function(n, beta0, beta1, beta2) {
>     x <- runif(n, 0, 10)
>     eta1 <- beta0 + beta1*x
>     eta2 <- eta1 + beta2
>     p1 <- exp(eta1)/(1+exp(eta1))
>     p2 <- exp(eta2)/(1+exp(eta2))
>     tmp <- runif(n)
>     y <- (tmp < p1) + (tmp < p2)
>     fit <- lrm(y~x)
>     fit$stats[5]
> }
>
> out <- replicate(1000, tmpfun(100, -1/2, 1/4, 1/4))
> mean( out < 0.05 )
> ```

I am looking to do the same thing for Difference-in-Difference Analysis. I am not sure how to adjust the parameters to fit a Difference-in-Difference. Does anybody have any suggestions?